# Count of atoms on the each level, Scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme

Please, help me with one simple exercise on the Scheme.

> Write  function, that return count of atoms on the each level in the
>   list. For example:
>
> (a (b (c (d e (f) k 1 5) e))) –> ((1 1) (2 1) (3 2) (4 5) (5 1))

My Solution:

```
(define (atom? x)
  (and (not (pair? x)) (not (null? x))))
(define (count L)
  (cond ((null? L) 0)
        ((pair? (car L))
         (count (cdr L)))
        (else
         (+ 1 (count (cdr L))))))
(define (fun L level)
  (cons 
   (list level (count L))
   (ololo L level)))
(define (ololo L level)
  (if (null? L)
      '()
      (if (atom? (car L))
          (ololo (cdr L) level)            
          (fun (car L) (+ level 1)))))
(fun '(a (b (c (d e (f) k 1 5) e))) 1)
```

It's work fine, but give not correctly answer for this list:

```
(a (b (c (d e (f) (k) 1 5) e)))
```

is:

```
((1 1) (2 1) (3 2) (4 4) (5 1))
```

But we assume that 'f' and 'k' on the one level, and answer must be:

```
((1 1) (2 1) (3 2) (4 4) (5 2))
```

How should I edit the code to make it work right?

---

UPD (29.10.12):
My final solution:

```
(define A '(a (b (c (d e (f) k 1 5) e))))

(define (atom? x)
  (and (not (pair? x)) (not (null? x))))

(define (unite L res)
  (if (null? L) (reverse res)
      (unite (cdr L) (cons (car L) res))))

(define (count-atoms L answ)
  (cond ((null? L) answ)
        ((pair? (car L))
         (count-atoms (cdr L) answ))
        (else
         (count-atoms (cdr L) (+ answ 1)))))

(define (del-atoms L answ)   
  (cond ((null? L) answ)
        ((list? (car L))
         (begin
         (del-atoms (cdr L) (unite (car L) answ))))
        (else
         (del-atoms (cdr L) answ))))

(define (count L)
(define (countme L level answ)
  (if (null? L)  (reverse answ)
      (countme (del-atoms L '()) (+ level 1) (cons (cons level (cons (count-atoms L 0) '())) answ))))
  (countme L 1 '()))

(count A)
```

What can you say about this?

Comment: I don't know how to work with hash-tabels in scheme. At this moment ;)

Comment: Something else about your design: having give the initial level to the top level function is clumsy and invites error; it's an internal implementation detail which should be hidden (unless you really want to give the user the option of starting from 0 or 1, say).  Create a function (**levelcount**, say) that simply takes a list as an argument, declare all your helper functions inside that and have it pass 1 (or 0) to the initial call to **fun**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know what you get if you run this?

```
(fun '(a (b (c (d e (f) k 1 5) e)) (a (b (c)))) 1)
```

You get this:

```
((1 1) (2 1) (3 2) (4 5) (5 1))
```

The whole extra nested structure that I added on the right has been ignored.  Here is why...

Each recursion of your function does two things:

1. Count all the atoms at the current "level"
2. Move down the level till you find an s-expression that is a pair (well, not an atom)

Once it finds a nested pair, it calls itself on that.  And so on

What happens in **oLoLo** when **fun** returns from the first nested pair? Why, it returns!  It does **not** keep going down the list to find another.

Your function will never find more than the first list at any level.  And if it did, what would you to do add the count from the first list at that level to the second?  You need to think carefully about how you recur completely through a list containing multiple nested lists **and** about how you could preserve information at each level.  There's more than one way to do it, but you haven't hit on any of them yet.

Comment: Thanks, I've realized my mistake. Now I need to think about it. I'm just a novice scheme-programmer. It's my first steps in functional programming. Thanks again.

Comment: It's a relatively complex problem for a novice.

Comment: Can you review my new solution? Please :-)

Answer (score 0):

Note that depending on your implementation, the library used here may need to be imported in some other way. It might be painstakingly difficult to find the way it has to be imported and what are the exact names of the functions you want to use. Some would have it as `filter` and `reduce-left` instead. `require-extension` may or may not be Guile-specific, I don't really know.

```
(require-extension (srfi 1))
(define (count-atoms source-list)
  (define (%atom? x) (not (or (pair? x) (null? x))))
  (define (%count-atoms source-list level)
    (if (not (null? source-list))
        (cons (list level (count %atom? source-list))
                (%count-atoms (reduce append '()
                       (filter-map
                        (lambda (x) (if (%atom? x) '() x))
                        source-list)) (1+ level))) '()))
  (%count-atoms source-list 1))
```

And, of course, as I mentioned before, it would be best to do this with hash-tables. Doing it with lists may have some didactic effect. But I have a very strong opposition to didactic effects that make you write essentially bad code.

Comment: It's not Guile-specific, but Guile and Gauche are the only implementations I'm aware of that support it out of the box.

Comment: Thanks! Nice example, I'll try to understand and do it myself :)